# WshShell keystroke multimedia Next Track windows

Tags: testing, keyboard-events, keystroke, wsh

I have a wscript that sends a keystroke to the active window.

I have the codes for keystroke for the following media keys:

Vol +  (code: &hAF)

Vol -  (code: &hAE)

Prev Track (code: &hB1)

Next Track (code: &hB0)  (not working)

Play/Pause (code: &hB3)

But i can't make it work the simulation of Next Track key, I think that it is related with the 0 in the hex code

This is the code to send keystroke keys:

```
'this script is working on W7 and W8    
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys(chr(&hB0)) 'change the chr argument by any hex to send keystrokes to the active window
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

I used as base this link to get the codes: http://orlando.mvps.org/SendKeysMore.asp

The problem is that instead of send the keystroke "Media Next", this send a keystroke  "°" to the active window

This hex (&hB0) translated to decimal is 176 and 176 is mapped to °

The help is very appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my problem. For some reason, I couldn't get the above code working.

Using other approach (and google) I found a C script

Is located here:
https://batchloaf.wordpress.com/2012/04/17/simulating-a-keystroke-in-win32-c-or-c-using-sendinput/

After test it, I  modified the code to can pass arguments:
posted here:
https://batchloaf.wordpress.com/2012/04/17/simulating-a-keystroke-in-win32-c-or-c-using-sendinput/#comment-4808

Arguments (key codes) was taken from:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx

I used Cygwin to compile the code, so if you want run the compiled code another machine you will need to have cygwin1.dll on the class path.

Comment: Thanks for documenting your solution.  You should mark your answer as accepted using the "tick" icon to the left of the answer.

Comment: Done! Done! Done!